# Remove column index from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I extracted multiple dataframes from excel sheet by passing cordinates (start & end)
Now i used below funtion to extacr according to cordinates, but when i am trying to 
convert it into dataframe, no sure from where index are coming in df as columns
I wanted to remove these index and make 2nd row as columns, this is my dataframe

```
         0     1     2    3     4    5     6
  Cols/Rows    A    A2    B    B2    C    C2
0         A   50    50   150    150  200   200
1         B  200    200  250    300  300   300
2         C  350    500  400    400  450   450

def extract_dataframes(sheet):                         
    ws = sheet['pivots']
    cordinates = [('A1', 'M8'), ('A10', 'Q17'), ('A19', 'M34'), ('A36', 'Q51')]
    multi_dfs_list = []
    for i in cordinates:
        data_rows = []
        for row in ws[i[0]:i[1]]:
            data_cols = []
            for cell in row:
                data_cols.append(cell.value)
            data_rows.append(data_cols)
        multi_dfs_list.append(data_rows)
    multi_dfs = {i: pd.DataFrame(df) for i, df in enumerate(multi_dfs_list)}
    return multi_dfs
```

I tried to delete index but not working.
Note: when i say

```
>>> multi_dfs[0].columns # first dataframe
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=13, step=1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
multi_dfs = {i: pd.DataFrame(df) for i, df in enumerate(multi_dfs_list)}
```

for

```
multi_dfs = {i: pd.DataFrame(df[1:], columns=df[0]) for i, df in enumerate(multi_dfs_list)}
```

From the [Docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html),

> columns : Index or array-like
>   Column labels to use for resulting frame. **Will default to RangeIndex (0, 1, 2, …, n) if no column labels are provided**

Answer (score 1):

I think need:

```
df = pd.read_excel(file, skiprows=1)
```

Comment: @TarunK that doesn't matter In this context

Comment: `previous_ = load_workbook(previous_file,                            read_only=True)`

Comment: I think he has lots of tables in the same excel worksheet and extracts many different `df`s from these tables. So he probably has to skip rows in between these tables too, I guess

Comment: @TarunK - Then super.